# Few questions about selendroid and appium

Tags: android, ios, mobile, appium, selendroid

I have gone through many blogs and tutorial on net to find out which is best tool to use for android & ios app. However, I came across selendroid and appium are widely used tool for mobile app automation. I have gone through multiple blogs and tutorial site and found information which are outdated older than 2015. Now, I want to know that

1. Which one is best among this two?
2. Does selendroid and appium test script can run on android and ios app without any change?
3. Advantage and disadvantage for this tools?
4. Do we have any other open source tools which are better than selendroid and appium?

I would appreciate your inputs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to your questions:

- If your are planning to use it for both iOS and android, i would suggest to go for Appium.
- Yes,  if your locators and app structure is same then you can use same script on both platforms.

**Appium**- Advantages:

- You can run test parallel
- Same scripts for both platforms is possible
- Doesn't require access to your source code so you are actually shipping what you are testing
- Good documentation and various blogs
- Support for various framework
- You can write test in your favorite language

**Disadvantage**

- Doesn't support image comparison

I have been using it for 3 months. This is what i have figured in 3 months.

Answer (score 1):

**Appium -**
 Pros-
1. Appium client libraries supports multiple languages hence you can write test cases in different languages like Java, Ruby, Python, PHP, JavaScript and C#.
2. Appium supports cross platfrom script development.
3. Appium has large community support where you ask and share.
4. It supportd test running on physical devices as well as Emulators.
5. Support for native and hybrid mobile application for android as well as iOS.
6. Record and play back is available for Mac OS

Cons- 
1. Record and play back is not available on Windows OS. 
Documentation is not user friendly.
3. Does not support image comparison.
4. Setting up takes some time especially in case of Linux system.
5. Limited Support for Gestures.
6. Limited support for android version < 4.1
7. No Support for Toast Messages.
8. Activities outside of app like camera,maps etc cannot be automates

**Selendroid -**

Pros -
1. Supports different languages same like Appium for eg. Java, C#, perl,python etc.
2. Supports test run on multiple devices and emulators.
3. Supports Native as well as hybrid app automation

Cons -

1.Limited Support for Gestures.
2. Limited support for android version < 4.1
3. No Support for Toast Messages.
4. Activities outside of app like camera,maps etc cannot be automates
5. Does not support iOS